# Rails slow to reload for a big project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with a big Rails 4.2 project and when I do `reload!` in the console, it's long to run. I measure it by doing `Benchmark.measure { reload! }.real` and it take 2.5 seconds. It appear to be quick but each time I save a file and run a test or do a request it reload the files so I have kind of results :

```
time spring rspec --color spec/models/content_thread_spec.rb:605
Running via Spring preloader in process 1016
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/content_thread_spec.rb"=>[605]}}

Randomized with seed 33718
.

Finished in 0.16152 seconds (files took 42.45 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 33718


real    0m1.736s
user    0m0.440s
sys     0m0.064s
c337ecbc2313 app # touch app/models/bla.rb
c337ecbc2313 app # time spring rspec --color spec/models/content_thread_spec.rb:605
33
Running via Spring preloader in process 1065
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/content_thread_spec.rb"=>[605]}}

Randomized with seed 33718
.

Finished in 0.17195 seconds (files took 1 minute 3 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 33718


real    0m4.521s
user    0m0.441s
sys     0m0.064s
```

As you can see, it took 1.7 seconds when I didn't change anything and, then I change any file in the project, it take 4.5 seconds. If I run the test once again, it will take 1.7 seconds. All files of the project are reloaded and files I change doesn't have to be related.

As I understand, each files are reloaded when I change a file. There is many files and I can see with `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.loaded.count` there is 803 files to load. It seems than all the files are in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.loaded`. All paths are in `Rails.configuration.autoload_paths`.

Is there a way to have a more wise solution and reload only needed files? Does all files have to be loaded?

Comment: What do your `autoload_paths` look like? You may have way too much in there so it's having to load too much. It should only include extra files in a `lib` folder or such that you need in your application.

Comment: I checked and I have more than 700 files in the app directory and 646 only for models. My autoload_paths load only files in lib.